# how to extract all attributes of json and map to flowfileattribute

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to know if any way is available to reverse "AttributesToJSON". Problem statement is, i am getting a json from 3rd party (it is single object, not an array). JSON is in flowfile content. now i want to put all attributes on json to flow-file attribute. and name of flowfile attribute to be same as json attribute.

so it is exactly opposite to AttributesToJSON when we keep "Attributes List" as blank.

I know i can extract attribute via EvaluateJsonPath, but this file can have attributes in 100s, and i do not want to introduce error due to programmer copy-paste. also I want to keep this part of code dynamic, if 101 attribute gets added to json, i want 101 attribute gets added to flow-file.

Comment: You can use script.

Comment: The answer below is technically correct for how you can do it with ExtractText, but in general I would question why you need to extract 100s of attributes, this could lead to degraded performance since attributes are held in memory and also have to be written to the flow file repo on every modification to the flow file

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ExtractText](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExtractText/index.html)(using `.*` capture group) to extract all of the json into one attribute, so you can then query this json using [jsonPath](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#jsonpath) function of expression language.
Example:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}
```

UpdateAttribute: a=`${myJsonAttribute:jsonPath('$.a')}` will result with an attribute named `a` with value `1`